# Loopback operation hook not triggering

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I have set an operation hook on my sales table, but the operation not triggering when a new row insert in that table. My hook coke has given below. The database is MySQL.

```
module.exports = function (LiveSales) {
  LiveSales.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
    var socket = LiveSales.app.io;
    console.log("New Item added");
    if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
    } else {
    }
    //Calling the next middleware..
    next();
  }); //after save..
}
```

Comment: What remote method are you calling to insert the row?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using after remote method.

```
  LiveSales.afterRemote('*.save', function(ctx, user, next) {
     var socket = LiveSales.app.io;
     console.log("New Item added");

     if (ctx.isNewInstance) {

     } else {

     }
     //Calling the next middleware..
     next();
   }); //after save..
  });
```

from [loopback docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are inserting data !
If you are inserting via API URL `/api/examples/create`

You should create a After Remote method like below :
Howerver you will not have this option `ctx.isNewInstance` context will contain these objects `req`, `res`, `args`, `result` check context objects [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html).

Below `user` will be the after remote result or `ctx.result`.

The **MEHTOD** can be : `create` for post or `patchOrCreate` for patch/upsert method

```
LiveSales.afterRemote(METHOD, function(ctx, user, next) {
     var socket = LiveSales.app.io;
     console.log("New Item added");

     if (user) {

      } else {

      }

     //Calling the next middleware..
     next();
   });
  });
```